# Is there a well known algorithm to discover the ID of each device in a daisy chain network?

Tags: algorithm, networking

Imagine I have say 6 intelligent devices all connected together end to end with a data link (could be two serial ports per device).  Each device has unique ID programmed into it and we want each device to work out where it is in the chain of devices. So with 6 devices my daisy might look like:

-[901]---[905]---[902]---[903]---[906]---[904]-

At the end of the 'discovery' algorithm each device would have the above map and know which device it is connected to on its left and right, if any for the end devices.  Each device would operate the same software and be identical to each other, apart from the unique ID.

Is there an easy way to do this without it getting too complicated ?  The number of devices in the chain could be variable but a maximum of 6.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to [ARP resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). Since there is a maximum of only 6 devices, a basic algorithm of broadcasting the request to the network (i.e. each device) would probably be the simplest way. Likewise, linearly passing the request wouldn't take much longer either.

If they are network devices with MAC addresses, you can even take advantage of these unique IDs instead of creating your own, if that's useful.

Comment: Broadcasting could be made to work if each node passes on every message it receives, however if the links are half duplex (RS485) then a mechanism is also required to handle data collisions and retries.  Ie for when two nodes send messages at the same time on the same wire.